# "I was to go to America at the end of the week. It would be the first time I had flown to America." Is the second sentence correct?

Tags: conditional-perfect, sequence-of-tenses, subordinate-clauses

I am using exactly the same sentence as the one used in a question already posted by someone else to ask whether one should not say and write "It will be the first time I fly to America." rather than "It will be the first time I have flown to America."

The question of what happens when the first verb is in the conditional (a future in the past: telling about someone who was about to do something) was not asked.

So, here it is…

Why should one say

> "It would be the first time I had flown to America."

rather than

> "* It would be the first time I would have flown to America.*"

or

> "* It would be the first time I have flown to America.*"

or

> " * It would be the first time I would fly to America.*"

or

> "* It would be the first time I flew to America.*"

?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a better fit for ELL than ELU.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: like this?

Comment: @tchrist: I agree. Is this really unproblematic to any native speaker of English, though?

Comment: what makes you think one should say "It would be the first time I had flown to America." in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the first sentence is correct: *I was to go to America at the end of the week*, meaning that you had planned to, but are no longer going to America at the end of the week, the correct second sentence would be the third conditional.

> It would have been the first time I had flown to America.

If the trip to America is still happening at the end of the week the sentences should read

> I am going to America at the end of the week. It will be the first time I have flown to America.

EDIT: I just saw some clarification and realize that we might be talking about the past.

If we are talking about a past time when the speaker was looking forward to a trip to America (both of which are now in the past), we could have

> I was to go to America at the end of the week. It would be the first time I had flown to America.

So, in short, apart from the missing *be*, I think that the sentences are correct.

Answer (score -1):

Two rules are implied in the choice of the right tense in a sentence such as "It would be the first time I had flown to America.":

1. When you do/did/will do/would do something for the first/second/third/etc time, the time period you are considering is a flashback, it moves from the point in time mentioned (the moment when I would fly to America) backwards to the person's birth to see how many times the action mentioned (flying to America) has been/had been/will have been/would have been repeated over this time period, so it is natural that the verb should be in a perfect simple tense rather than in a simple tense;

   - *It would be the first time I would have flown to America.** (perfect tense needed)
2. In time clauses – and "It is/was/will be/would be the first time that…" is followed by a time clause – future tenses are replaced with present tenses, and conditional tenses with past tenses, the aspects – simple, continuous, perfect simple, perfect continous – remaining the same;

   *It would be the first time I had flown to America.* (conditional perfect simple replaced with past perfect simple)

Comment: Is it too difficult to follow or are you simply allergic to rules?!

Comment: I did not know even answers could go grey!

Answer (score -2):

- **Situation 1**: you're on the plane for the US and are telling your seat neighbor it's the first time you flew to America.

> It **is** the first time I **have flown** to America.

Or, more colloquially:

> It **is** the first time I **flew** to America.

- **Situation 2**: you went to America two months ago and are talking to someone about it.

> "It **was** the first time I **had flown** to America."

Or, more colloquially:

> "It **was** the first time I **flew** to America."

- **Situation 3**: you're flying to America at the end of the week, and are talking to someone about it.

If you're telling the story in the present, use:

> "It **will be** the first time I **fly** to America."

If you're telling the story in the past, you should say:

> "It **would be** the first time I **flew** to America."

- **Situation 4** (like in your example): you were supposed to fly to America at the end of the week but, for some reason, the trip was canceled. You're talking to a friend about it.

> "Sigh, it **would have been** the first time I **had flown** to America."

Or, more colloquially and nonstandard:

> "Sigh, it **would have been** the first time I **would have flown** to America."

Comment: What dialect do you speak? I find your "will" and "would" versions unidiomatic; I would say "It **will be** the first time I **fly** to America" and "It **would be** the first time I **flew** to America." (I notice that you live in France; maybe that's influencing your English? French would use the future tense in this case, *la première fois que je voyagerai aux États-Unis*, but that doesn't necessarily carry over to English.)

Comment: Still not quite right: *It is the first time I have flown to America* is what you might say to the person sitting next to you in the airliner, not talking about two months ago. Similarly, if you really are talking now about a conversation you had last month talking about your flight two months ago, the form is *It had been the first time I had flown* [or colloquially *the first time I flew*]. This is rare.